# translate POST request to API in PHP to Swift

Tags: php, swift, xcode, rest, curl

Hello I'm trying to translate POST request api code written in php:

```php
<?php
$methodParams = '{
    "date_confirmed_from": 1407341754,
    "get_unconfirmed_orders": false
}';
$apiParams = [
    "method" => "getOrders",
    "parameters" => $methodParams
];

$curl = curl_init("https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["X-BLToken: xxx"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiParams));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

To Swift but I don't have idea why it doesn't work:

```
import UIKit

struct Parameters: Codable {
    let date_confirmed_from: Int
    let get_unconfirmed_orders: Bool
}

struct BodyData: Codable {
    let method: String
    let parameters:Parameters
}

let url = URL(string: "https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
    "X-BLToken": "xxx"
]

let bodyData = BodyData(method: "getOrders", parameters: Parameters(date_confirmed_from: 1407341754, get_unconfirmed_orders: false))
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let encodeData = try encoder.encode(bodyData)
    request.httpBody = encodeData
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if  let data = data {

        }
    }
    task.resume()
    
    
}catch {
    print(error)
}
```

When I'm testing my Swift code I'm getting error answer from API can someone help me to find fault in my code?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: have you tried adding: `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` and
     `request.addValue("X-BLToken \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`
      where token is your value, instead of using `request.allHTTPHeaderFields...`. P.S, is there a "demo" token that can be used to test the api? It makes it so much easier when we can test various options, rather then guessing an answer.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine yes I tried that and still got error. Unfortunately no there isn't demo token

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine This is my error: `{"status":"ERROR","error_code":"ERROR_UNKNOWN_METHOD","error_message":"An empty or unknown method has been used"}`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Sorry I find out solution for free demo API you can create account on [link](https://baselinker.com/en-US/home/) and then you are able to use API

Comment: sorry but the link for a free account ask a lot of info, including tax number etc... and at the end it does not work. It could be some phishing scam.

Comment: This is too difficult to read, I posted it as an answer:  Does the PHP curl work?  It is not what the baseline documentation is asking for.  The documentation asks for post data: `$_POST
array (
  'method' => 'getOrders',
  'parameters' => '{"date_from": 1407341754}',
)`
Your PHP curl request:
'array (
  'method' => 'getOrders',
  'parameters' => '{
    "date_confirmed_from": 1407341754,
    "get_unconfirmed_orders": false
}',
)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I find out solution for this problem:

```swift
import UIKit

let url = URL(string: "https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("xxx",forHTTPHeaderField: "X-BLToken")

let data: Data = "method=getOrders&parameters={\"date_confirmed_from\": 1407341754&\"get_unconfirmed_orders\":false}".data(using: .utf8)!
    request.httpBody = data
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if  let data = data {
            let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print(dataString!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

The biggest problem was coding of data. ***curl*** in PHP by default sending data as x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

Does the PHP curl work?  
It is not what the baseline documentation is asking for.  
The documentation asks for this post data:

```
array (
  'method' => 'getOrders',
  'parameters' => '{"date_from": 1407341754}',
)
```

Your PHP curl request post data:

```
'array (
  'method' => 'getOrders',
  'parameters' => '{
    "date_confirmed_from": 1407341754,
    "get_unconfirmed_orders": false
}',
)'
```

The documentation asks
*parameters = arguments of the requested function in JSON format*.
Your parameters are an array, not JSON.